# bootstrap 3 navbar button functionality

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a reoccurring issue i always run into with navbars. I always have a button that has a method that wont get executed until I move it from within the navbar to actually inside of the app. How do I avoid this or execute the method from the navbar outside of the app? As you can see the logout button works fine on the page but not within navbar.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
     
    ]
  },
  methods: {
     logout() {
     alert("test");
            localStorage.removeItem("user");
            window.location.reload(true);
          },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <link
      href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">test</a>
          <button v-on:click="logout()" class="btn btn-primary">logout</button>
      </nav>
      
   <div id="app">
  <h2>my app:</h2>
  <button v-on:click="logout()" class="btn btn-primary">logout</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query document and listen to event:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: []
  },
  mounted() {
    document.querySelector('.outside').addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.logout()
    })
  },
  methods: {
    logout() {
      alert("test");
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">test</a>
    <button v-on:click="logout()" class="btn btn-primary outside">logout</button>
  </nav>
  <div id="app">
  <h2>my app:</h2>
  <button v-on:click="logout()" class="btn btn-primary">logout</button>
</div>
```